# Is there anyway to create a pivot table with all these calculated fields?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table of Name, date (every day of the year), and hours. I am trying to create a pivot table to analyze the compliance of the data. By that I mean, I need to know for every year how many people are complainant with the 1800 limit (sum of all hours for the year) and how many are not.
i created the required results via 4 tables see image  but because i am using so many table, i am unable to do any drilldown/drill up analyzes. Is there a way to combine all of this in one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Pivot Table to the Data Model and then create three new measures:

```
CompliantCheck :=
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( Table1[Name] ),
    IF ( SUM ( Table1[Hours] ) > 1800, "Non-Compliant", "Compliant" ),
    ""
)

CompliantCount :=
IF (
    [CompliantCheck] = "",
    "",
    0
        + CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( [Name] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( Table1[Name] ), [CompliantCheck] = "Compliant" )
        )
)

NonCompliantCount :=
IF (
    [CompliantCheck] = "",
    "",
    0
        + CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( [Name] ),
            FILTER ( ALL ( Table1[Name] ), [CompliantCheck] = "Non-Compliant" )
        )
)
```

Obviously change the names of the table and fields in the above if necessary. Your Pivot Table should then comprise:

Rows: `Name` and `Fiscal Year`

Values: `Sum of Hours`, `Compliant Check`, `CompliantCount`, `NonCompliantCount`

Comment: Is there any way to return the table only with the rows of "Non-Compliant"?

Comment: Create a new measure: `CompliantFilter:=IF([CompliantCheck]="Non-Compliant",1,0)` and then do a `Value Filter` on the `Fiscal Year` column and set `CompliantFilter` equal to 1.

Comment: It still not the right display (see image above attached updated.) The return is all the rows for a Name that have atleast one "Non-Compliant". I need ONLY the rows with non-compliant. @JosWoolley